# jquery attribute text

Tags: jquery

given the following markup

```
<ul class="ulGreen">
                <li><b>On-Board systems - Road Vehicle</b><span style="color:black;"> (See an installation picture<a href="#" data-rel="onBoardVehiclepicdisplay">here</a>)</span> </li>
                <li><b>On-Board systems - Marine Vessel</b><span style="color:black;"> (See an installation picture<a href="#" data-rel="onBoardVesselpicdisplay">here</a>)</span> </li>
                <li><b>On-Board systems - FuelingBarge</b><span style="color:black;"> (See an installation picture<a href="#" data-rel="onBoardFuelBargepicdisplay">here</a>)</span> </li>

            </ul>
```

and the following script

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('.ulGreen').delegate(' li span a').click(function() {
            var divID = $(this).attr("data-rel").text;
            alert(divID);

        });
    });

</script>
```

divID should contain the text from the data-rel attribute of the clicked a tag, but it doesn't or you wouldn't be reading this. The HTML renders exactly as shown above.

Comment: Couple of things:
1) text() is not meant to extract the value of the attributes, attr is both a setter and a getter, you don't need to use it here.
2) This, at the time of the click, is the .ulGreen element, not the anchor you are clicking on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, use [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) to reference `data-` attributes.

But the real problem is in using [`delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) in this manner. When using `find()`, it works just fine (see [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LKgJ4/)):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.ulGreen').find('li span a').click(function() {
        var divID = $(this).data("rel");
        alert(divID);
    });
});​
```

If you need the live-updating event (and are using jQuery 1.7+), use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) (see [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LKgJ4/1/)):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.ulGreen').on('click', 'li span a', function() {
        var divID = $(this).data("rel");
        alert(divID);
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

The `text()` method returns a string, which has no `text()` method, simply omit that method-call:

```
$('.ulGreen').delegate('li span a').click(function(e) {
    var divID = $(e.target).attr("data-rel");
    alert(divID);
});​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/SKqdr/1/).

The `e.target` refers to the element clicked (the target of the event, `e`), whereas `this` (and the jQuery object `$(this)`) referred to the `ul` itself.